# Fontconfig error on Qnx

Tags: qt, fonts, qnx

I am using Qnx on PandaBoard Es and try to develope Qt application.

If I run qt application on qnx,I get error as following

> Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Apllication is open but fonts aren't shown. 
What can I do solve this problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [this instruction](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QNX_Platform) and applied decribed tips? By default "QNX SDP 6.6 does not provide fontconfig" so I think you should install some additional packages.